# How box allocated instance is retained in Swift closure?

Tags: swift, closures, retain-cycle

I'm trying to understand how box allocated instance are retained.
On the screen here, we

```
class A {
    deinit {
        print("deleted")
    }
}

var closure: (() -> Void)!

if true {
    var aa: A? = A()
    closure = {
        // Box wraps Optional<A> without creating new variable, it destroyed cuz it follows outer changes to variable
        print(aa)
    }

    aa = nil
}

closure() // output: deleted; nil
```

That's okey, this is what I expect expect, as i mentioned because -> Box wraps `Optional<A>` without creating new variable, it destroyed cuz it

Next example legit too:

```
class A {
    deinit {
        print("deleted")
    }
}

var closure: (() -> Void)!

if true {
    var aa: A? = A()
    closure = { [weak aa] in
        // creating a weak variable, that ends up when scope is over. That's okay
        print(aa)
    }

}

closure() // output: deleted; nil
```

But this example, get me confused a bit

```
class A {
    deinit {
        print("deleted")
    }
}

var closure: (() -> Void)!

if true {
    var aa: A? = A()
    closure = {
        // Box retains Optional<A> without creating new variable after if scope end, it doesn't destroyed? But why?
        print(aa)
    }
}

closure() // output: Optional(__lldb_expr_27.A)
```

Why in last example when scope is over, box allocated instance still gets retained?
Is there some implicit copying when scope is over?

Comment: `aa` is captured by `closure`, which is still in scope.

Comment: Nah, scope is over, optional is value type, so capturing doesn't create new variable it put it on heap via box. 
I'm interested in how does box keeps instance alive after scope?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand is happening.

When you do

```
var aa: A? = A()
```

Only `self` has a strong reference to `aa` so `aa` reference count is 1.

When you do

```
if true {
    var aa: A? = A()

    closure = {
        print(aa)
    }
}
```

Because `closure` requires `aa`, `closure` also has a strong reference to `aa` now so `aa` reference count is 2.

When you go out of scope, `self` no longer points to `aa` and its reference count decreases by 1 but `aa` cannot be deinitialized because its reference count is not 0 since closure strongly references it.

[image: Closure strong weak ARC reference retain cycle swift]

[image: ARC retain cycle swift Closure strong weak reference]